# OVH API Error: This call has not been granted

Tags: python, ovh

I need to use OVH API in my Python code but the call returns this error:

> OVH API Error: This call has not been granted

```
import json                                                          
import ovh

client = ovh.Client(
    endpoint='ovh-eu',
    application_key='application_key',                                              
    application_secret='application_secret',                                
    consumer_key='consumer_key',                          
)


project_id = 'project_id '                            

try:
    result = client.get(
        '/cloud/project/' + project_id + '/image',                    
        flavorType=None,
        osType=None,
        region='SBG5'
    )
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
    
except ovh.APIError as e:
    print(f"OVH API Error: {str(e)}")
    print(f"OVH Query ID: {e.response.headers.get('X-Ovh-Queryid')}")
```

- test in API.OVH.com console is working

return this :

(venv) PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\pythonFiles\Ovh> python step1_list_services.py

OVH API Error: This call has not been granted

OVH-Query-ID: EU.ext-3.655b414a.69585.e84e84691cd2e05baa9eec9585016b18

OVH Query ID: EU.ext-3.655b414a.69585.e84e84691cd2e05baa9eec9585016b18

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because the API call you're trying (`GET /cloud/project/{project_id}/image`) is not granted for the token you generated.

When you generate a token, you need to specify for which API path and HTTP verb (`GET`, `POST` etc) this token needs to be granted.

You can specify which API path/HTTP verb needs to be granted in two different ways:

- via UI: https://www.ovh.com/auth/api/createToken. You need to fill the `Rights` part. It accept regex. For instance: `GET` on `/cloud*`
- via `curl`: create an App in https://www.ovh.com/auth/api/createApp, and grant it on the needed route with:

```bash
$ curl -X POST \
     -H "X-Ovh-Application: <application_key>" \
     -H "Content-type: application/json" \
     https://eu.api.ovh.com/1.0/auth/credential \
     -d '{
            "accessRules": [
                {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "path": "/cloud*"
                },
                {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "path": "/cloud*"
                },
            ],
            "redirection": "https://ovhcloud.com/"
        }'
```

You will find the complete documentation about API [here](https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/en-gb-api-getting-started-ovhcloud-api?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0042784).